# Windows Authentication message in MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication

The Windows Authentication uses following dialog window for users who is not authenticated through NTLM:

[image: Login Dialog]

Users without being the right permissions gets the same login dialog, that prompts to provide another credentials.

Is there way to append a custom message to the dialog via controller context or `AuthorizeAttribute`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a browser native dialog prompt so you can not change it. One solution is to implement Forms authentication, create your own login dialog, and in the backend check the credentials against Active Directory.

Comment: It's a pity... :(

Comment: Maybe it is. But when you implement your custom dialog you can make it how you want. If you want I can dig somewhere the code I used for this same situation.